# Asus K501UX Touchpad starts working with 30 seconds delay after sleep mode

Tags: touchpad, laptop, asus

I installed Elementary OS yesterday as the first Linux in my life, so I'm total newbie here. I have a small problem with my touchpad. After I open my laptop and log in I have to wait some time because I can't move a pointer. It reacts if I click or tap it, but doesn't move for some time. Could you please help me with that?
 Also I'd like to add some gestures in addition to two-finger scrolling, but I suppose it will be another question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember how to check what your touchpad model is.

If you have an elantouchpad, which ASUS uses frequently, you will have this problem. I spent 2 days trying ways to fix it without luck. You will need to get a mouse, there just are not Ubuntu drivers for that model touchpad that effectively work.

I assume that is the problem you are running into here.

Comment: Well, yes, xinput says it's an elan touchpad. It's a pity.

Comment: Yeah, it is. It is quite disappointing. I was also looking for like a small USB touchpad that I could kinda just put over the current touchpad and those don't exist too. It has been an issue for quite a while and I doubt it will be fixed soon. :(

Answer (score 0):

**Old answer but for the second question :**

Nice to know you started linux. I wanted to exploit as much as possible the Touchpad of my Dell XPS 13 laptop with multi-finger motion function.

So here is a tool that I use now with my laptop daily

https://github.com/bulletmark/libinput-gestures

---

Having automated this task for the installation of Elementary OS on one of my GITHUB repository.

## SCRIPT

```
# Add the actual user in the input group
sudo gpasswd -a $USER input

# install dependencies
sudo apt install xdotool wmctrl

# install other dependancies for Elementary OS (Ubuntu)
sudo apt install libinput-tools

# Clone the repo
git clone https://github.com/bulletmark/libinput-gestures.git

# Change dorictory
cd libinput-gestures

# Install
sudo make install

# Chnage dorictory to HOME USER
cd

# Remove directory
sudo rm -rf libinput-gestures

# enable autostart the service
libinput-gestures-setup autostart
```

is better if your reboot after

enjoy